# What is the ApplicationContactURI in a trusted Lync application?

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I have got a lot of information from my Lync Server administrator, for making a Trusted Application, but it is required to enter the Application Contact URI, and I can not find that information.

When I run the application, with the information I think might be correct, I get this error:

```
Platform started...
Establishing the endpoint...
Application Endpoint established...
Endpoint: Idle sip:xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx
The Application endpoint is not currently in the Established state, exiting...
```

This is based on the trusted application sample which comes with the UCMA sdk.

I can not get it to go into Established state, and as I said, the only information I seem to be missing is the application contact uri.

I am not able to get in touch with the Lync Server administrator within the next few days! :( So please help.

Answer (score 0):

Seamed you already got your answer in the Microsoft forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/39a90313-dbbd-4f25-8ade-bbdc41eee484/what-is-the-applicationcontacturi?forum=ucmanagedsdk), which is:

```
< add key=”applicationName” value=”yourApplicationName”/ >
< add key=”gruu” value=” < your trusted application’s gruu you get it after creating the trusted application on powershell> ”/ >
< add key=”listeningPort” value=” < your trusted application’s listening port > ”/ >
< add key=”contactUri” value=” < contact uri for your application which must be a free uri using it when creating the trusted application endpoint > ”/ >
< add key=”proxyServerFqdn” value=” < CS server FQDN > ”/ >
```